# Crontab Script File Syntax

Tags: shell, cron, freebsd

I am in a UNIX system administration course at school and have to generate a Cron job that does the following:

- Queries the system each hour to find
  out who is logged in.
- Mails the result to my email account.

I know that the actual crontab will look like the following:

```
# Check to see who is logged in every hour.
MAILTO="me@email.com"
0       *       *       *       *       root    /tmp/loggedin.sh
```

OR

```
# Check to see who is logged in every hour.
MAILTO="me@email.com"
@hourly /tmp/loggedin.sh
```

But I have been Googling for some time and have been unable to find any examples of what exactly the .sh file should look like. I know it starts with:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Shell script to see who is logged in, to be run every hour.
```

And I have no idea what else to put in there. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you want to find out `who` is logged in?

Comment: Yes, and the comment below is helpful, but I'm not sure how to get it to run the .sh file I have at /etc/loggedin.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `who` should do the trick. It will show you a list of all the users that are logged in to the system at a time. You can write this to a file and then have it mailed to you.

`w` would get you what the people logged in are currently doing.

So, the script would look like:

```
#!/bin/sh  
HOME=<your home directory>
who > ${HOME}/usersLoggedIn.txt  
w > ${HOME}/whatLoggedInUsersAreDoing.txt
```

`${HOME}` refers to your home directory. On the command prompt, `echo $HOME` should give you your home directory. The output of the command `who` and `w` will get redirected to the files `usersLoggedIn.txt` and `whattLoggedInUsersAreDoing.txt` within your home directory. You can, of course, change the directory and file names to which you want this data to be written.

HTH,
Sriram

Comment: What does the ${HOME} variable refer to? And how does that tell it to email me the results? Because I just tried it out and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Any output from a cron job is mailed to the user. If you don't care about the subject line your cron entry is as simple as this:

```
@hourly w
```

If you do care about it,use mail(1):

```
@hourly w|mail -s'Users logged in' me@work.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Shell script to see who is logged in, to be run every hour.
who | mail -s "Who is logged in `date`" "$MAILTO"
```